# How can I update the "Important" field, which is stored in a subcollection?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How can I update the "Important" field, which is stored in a subcollection?

[image: See image to understand better]

```
import firebaseApp from "../../utils/firebase";
import { getFirestore, doc, updateDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
const firestoreDB = getFirestore(firebaseApp);
const USER_DATA = "UsersData";
const TASKS = "Tasks";

const updateImportantValue = async (userID, newValue) => {
  try {
    const docRef = doc(
      firestoreDB,
      USER_DATA,
      userID,
      TASKS,
      "EyS9R8dHV3EU3WS2PeQo"
    );

    await updateDoc(docRef, {
      important: newValue,
    });

    console.log(firestoreDB);
    console.log(USER_DATA);
    console.log(userID);
    console.log(TASKS);
    console.log(newValue);

    console.log("updateImportantValue - success");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

I tried this way but it throws me an error:

TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function

```
at Function.fromString (index.esm2017.js:1084:1)
at ia (index.esm2017.js:16166:1)
at updateImportantValue (updateImportantValue.js:9:1)
at removeImportant (useTask.js:76:1)
at importantButton (TaskData.js:16:1)
at onClick (TaskData.js:37:1)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4070:1)
```

Update

Update, I was not receiving the User ID correctly. I corrected the error and the console indicates that everything was correct, but in firestore the document does not undergo any change, the "important" field remains the same.

[console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj65C.png)

Comment: What error does it throw? `USER_DATA`, `userID` and `TASKS` are all defined right?

Comment: Yes, all variables are defined. Update the question with the error

Comment: Can you `console.log(firestoreDB, USER_DATA, userID, TASKS)` and share a screenshot of output?

Comment: I had an error in the user id. I fixed it and there are no more errors, but the document in firestore remains the same. Edit the question with more details and the console.log

Comment: Sorry, again it was my mistake. I was trying to modify other documents. When the document ID in updateImportantValue() was always the same. Everything is fixed now, thanks.